# Check to see if an log event occurs in NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to check to see if a log event happens in my app, and if it does something.

I have checked everywhere and can't seem to find any info on if an log event even happens.

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info("Info Log Message");
if(logger.event == true)
{
    //an log even happen this run
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting down a breakpoint and debugging your application ?

Comment: That I have. The program runs fine . But I breakpoint it so see if there is any event firing counts in the logger/LogManger and there isn't that i can find..   =/

Comment: Are you just trying to see if `logger.Info()` (replace info w/ all possible logging levels) is called any point, or are you trying to determine if NLog is writing to your target(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can use the `MethodCall` target to accomplish this.

You can add a target entry to your `NLog.config` file that would direct log events to a static method in one of your classes. See the [documentation](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/MethodCall-target) for more details on how to do that.

You can also directly do it in code as shown below (example copied here from documentation):

```
using NLog;
using NLog.Targets;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Example
{
    public static void LogMethod(string level, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("l: {0} m: {1}", level, message);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodCallTarget target = new MethodCallTarget();
        target.ClassName = typeof(Example).AssemblyQualifiedName;
        target.MethodName = "LogMethod";
        target.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("${level}"));
        target.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("${message}"));

        NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(target, LogLevel.Debug);

        Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");
        logger.Debug("log message");
        logger.Error("error message");
    }
}
```

---

I just realized my answer about might not answer your question if you're only wanting to check if a specific logger is called. If so, you can use rules to only get events from a certain logger as shown in [Logger-specific routing](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#logger-specific-routing) section of the documentation.

You'd need to add an entry to the `<rules>` section of your `NLog.config` that references the target you've defined. I don't know if there's a way to setup your target in-code and combine it with this rule. You might have to define the target in the config file:

```
<targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="SomeNamespace.Component.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
</rules>
```

Comment: I've just answered on similar question, that Memory target can be used instead of MethodCall http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391792/functional-test-based-on-nlog-output/41404920#41404920