# Functional test based on nlog output

Tags: c#, testing, nlog

I got some tests which relies on the output from Nlog. I've [managed to redirect the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848095/check-to-see-if-an-log-event-occurs-in-nlog/30849796#30849796) to a variable so I can dive into the string to figured out if all went ok. There must be a better way of doing this but I couldn't manage to find anything.

Here's the test and the class being tested:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ProcessMessagesFromQueues
{
    private static string StuffLogged;

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        StuffLogged = string.Empty;
        RedirectNLog();
    }

    private static void RedirectNLog()
    {
        MethodCallTarget target = new MethodCallTarget();
        target.ClassName = typeof(ProcessMessagesFromQueues).AssemblyQualifiedName;
        target.MethodName = "LogMethod";
        target.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("${message}"));

        NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(target, LogLevel.Debug);
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetNewSmsMessageWhenPublished()
    {
        // Subscribe
        var sqs = FluentNotificationStack.Register(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.Component = "privateapnworker";
            configuration.Environment = "qa28";
            configuration.Tenant = "uk";
        });

        sqs
        .WithSqsTopicSubscriber()
        .IntoQueue("")
        .WithMessageHandler(new ConfigurationSmsHandler())
        .StartListening();

        // Publish
        sqs.WithSnsMessagePublisher<ConfigurationSmsSent>();

        string fakeImei = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        string expected = $"Configuration SMS captured! Imei: {fakeImei} status StatusOk{Environment.NewLine}";

        sqs.Publish(new ConfigurationSmsSent(fakeImei, "StatusOk"));

        // Wait for it
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // 4. Compare the messages
        StringAssert.Contains(expected, StuffLogged);
    }

    public static void LogMethod(string message)
    {
        StuffLogged += message + Environment.NewLine;
    }

}
```

The class with the output:

```
public class ConfigurationSmsHandler : IHandler<ConfigurationSmsSent>
{
    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public bool Handle(ConfigurationSmsSent message)
    {
        Logger.Info($"Configuration SMS captured! Imei: {message.Imei} status {message.Status}");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to the MethodCall target, [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30849796/52277) by [Jeff Bridgman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/945456/jeff-bridgman), 
you can specify NLog [Memory-target](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Memory-target) 
and verify output in target.Logs

```
 MemoryTarget target = new MemoryTarget();
    target.Layout = "${message}";

    NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(target, LogLevel.Debug);

    Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");
    logger.Debug("log message");

    foreach (string s in target.Logs)
    {
        Console.Write("logged: {0}", s);
    }
```